# mainthread does not wait for the parallel.foreach end

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm going crazy for a problem in my code.

I'm working with a library named "Interop.Automation.dll" that provides an event "dataChange" to which i attached an handler.

At a certain point in my code the mainThread starts a Parallel.Foreach

```
Parallel.ForEach(aOPCItems.Cast<OPCItem>().ToList(), (item) =>
{
    if (item.CanonicalDataType > 8000) 
    {
        return;
    }

    IOPCItem itemTemp = new AutomationItem(item);
    Monitor.Enter(listOPCItems);
    listOPCItems.Add(itemTemp);
    Monitor.Exit(listOPCItems);

    Monitor.Enter(opcItemDict);
    if (!opcItemDict.ContainsKey(item.ClientHandle))
    {
        opcItemDict.Add(item.ClientHandle, itemTemp);
    }
    Monitor.Exit(opcItemDict);

});
```

The mainThread starts execution of Parallel.Foreach body for some items.

During this Parallel.Foreach the dataChage event seems to be triggering and mainthread goes to execute the handler's code.

No code in Parallel.Foreach can fire the event.

Stopping the execution with break point in handler's code i can see that mainthread is working there, and the workingThreads work in a Paralle.Foreach body.

When the mainThread ends the work in handler's code and the workingThread end the work in a Parallel.Foreach body, than the mainThread continues with the code under Parallel.Foreach.

Is it a normal behavior for mainThread leave to Parallel.Foreach to go to execute handler's code and than return back?

This is the call stack during mainThread executes the handler's code

[image]

This is the code in AutomationItem constructor

```
private string _itemName;
private OPCItem _item;
private object _value;
private string _quality;

Array ItemServerHandles = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Int32), 2);
int cancelID;
int transactionID = 1;

public AutomationItem(OPCItem item)
{
     _item = item;
     if (item.Quality == 192)
     {
         _quality = "Good";
     }
     else
     {
         _quality = 
((OPCQuality)item.Quality).ToString().Replace("OPCQuality", String.Empty);
     }
     _itemName = item.ItemID;
     ItemServerHandles.SetValue(item.ServerHandle, 1);
 }
```

EDIT:
I've replaced Parallel.Foreach with normal foreach, the behavior persists.
The stack trace is similar.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, can you be more specific, also what handler code

Comment: This is interesting.  Looks like the COM interop, when a COM event is raised, steals your thread from its wait state to execute the COM event.  However, I can't find anything like this in the reference source.  Are you sure this COM event handled **while** your code is in the `Parallel.ForEach` block?

Comment: Could there be anything hidden in the AutomationItem constructor or those Add() methods? The word ClientHandle stands out.

Comment: @Nick as i wrote above:
"Stopping the execution with break point in handler's code i can see that mainthread is working there, and the workingThreads work in a Paralle.Foreach body".
This means that if i select mainthread and i push step over, mainThread exeutes code in the handler. If i select workerThread and push step over, workerThread executes code in Paralle.Foreach.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Add methods are simple add on the list. I've edited the post with AutomationItem ctor.

Comment: What types are the lists? Do they implement INotifyCollectionChanged and your using that event?

Comment: @MartinGrundy listOPCItems is a List<IOPCItem>, opcItemsDicti is Dictionary<Int64, IOPCItem>. They do not implement INotifyCollectionChanged. AutomationItem (class writed by me) is only a wrapper for OPCItem (Automation.dll). There is a OPCServer object (from Automation.dll) to witch i add a OPCGroup (Automation.dll) to witch i add OPCItems (Automation.dll) (aOPCItems in my code). When i create the OPCGroup instance also i attach OPCGroup.datachange += myHanlder; 
I don't know the code in Automation.dll.

Comment: @MirkoCollura, you are right. This is very weird.  Looks like thread stealing to me, though I can't possibly understand how by just looking at the source code.  My only guess would be that perhaps COM interop uses [APC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/types-of-apcs).  But it is a very wild guess. :-(

Comment: @MirkoCollura - You say 'a OPCGroup (Automation.dll) to witch i add OPCItems (Automation.dll) (aOPCItems in my code).' so it could be that action of adding to the OPCGroup which is triggering the event as that is the class which generates it, dependant on how that library is written it could be throttled/delayed in some way.